# How to add nodes and edges while setting their keys using for loops?

Tags: python, for-loop, networkx

I am new to python and i need to solve a problem using min_cost_flow, my question may seem rudimentary but i was wondering how i can use for loops to name my nodes and edges something like:

```
for cp in range (1,50):
    G.add_node(cp, demand[cp-1])
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the data you want to encode in your graph?

Comment: I have a list for the demands, i need to have a graph with each node being a customer with the demand that has to be read from the list (i.e. node[1] has the demand [1]) and also anther sets of nodes for suppliers. then the arches are going to be between the supplier nodes and the demand nodes, the weight and capacities need to be read from two other list. i wanted to know if it is possible to name the nodes as node[i] and put i in the for loop!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed a demand list where the name of the nodes to be created are stored. here is the code for doing it:

```
g=nx.Graph()
demands = ['d_1','d_2','d_3']
for i in xrange(3):
    g.add_node(demands[i])
nx.draw(g,with_labels = True, node_size = 500)
plt.show()
```

Attached is the resulting graph.[image]